# How to insert and or update a variable number of records and prevent concurrency issues

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, concurrency, isolation-level

I currently have the following stored procedure. However I am seeing some race conditions where I end up with incorrect data which I think is caused because the procedure isn't attomic and it can be called multiple times resulting in overlapping data.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[data_save]
    @user INT ,
    @players VARCHAR(MAX) ,
    @captains VARCHAR(MAX)
AS

-- Clear existing records if any    
DELETE FROM dbo.data WHERE user = @user

DECLARE @captainsTable TABLE (captainId INT);
INSERT INTO @captainsTable (captainId)
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 3 item FROM [platform].[SimpleSplit](@captains, ',')

INSERT INTO dbo.data
( user ,
  player ,
  iscaptain
)
SELECT @user
     , item -- this is what is returned from the SimpleSplit
     , CASE WHEN [item] in (select captainId from @captainsTable) THEN 1
         ELSE 0
       END
  FROM [platform].[SimpleSplit](@captains, ',')
```

I want to be able to execute this concurrently for different users but not for the same user.

The number of records for one user might be 4 at point 1 in time and then in point 2 the save might be executed with 6 records for instance. So just updating the existing records is not an option.

It's not a problem if the last call to the save procedure "wins" and overwirtes the previous ones but I don't want to end up with a combination of data from both. I am using sql server 2008.

Answer (score 3):

If your goal is to ensure that at the end of procedure `dbo.data` contains only records you inserted in the body of procedure, then you move `DELETE` to the very end (I assume you have primary key in `data` table, `data_id`:

```
--DELETE FROM dbo.data WHERE user = @user  -- do it at the end    
DECLARE @captainsTable TABLE (captainId INT);
DECLARE @newData TABLE (data_id INT);
INSERT INTO @captainsTable (captainId)
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 3 item FROM [platform].[SimpleSplit](@captains, ',')

--store inserted rows into table
INSERT INTO dbo.data
( user ,
  player ,
  iscaptain
)
OUTPUT inserted.data_id INTO @newData
SELECT @user
     , item -- this is what is returned from the SimpleSplit
     , CASE WHEN [item] in (select captainId from @captainsTable) THEN 1
         ELSE 0
       END
  FROM [platform].[SimpleSplit](@captains, ',');
--delete all except recently inserted
DELETE b FROM dbo.data b WHERE user = @user AND NOT EXISTS
(SELECT NULL FROM @newData a WHERE a.data_id = b.data_id);
```

Also, it makes sense to begin transaction (or create a savepoint if the sp executed withing the context of existing transaction) in the beginning of procedure , and commit at the end.